# Mapstruct test could not autowire in SpringBoot test

Tags: java, spring-boot, testing, mapping, mapstruct

I've just added Mapstruct library to my project and I'm trying to figure out how it works. When trying to run test case, my mapper object is null and I can't figure out why. This is how I've defined the interface:

```
@Mapper(componentModel = "spring")
public interface ReviewMapper {
    RideReview toRideReviewEntity(ReviewDTO reviewDTO);
}
```

So from what I've read in other topics, the `componentModel="spring"` should do the trick with instantiating the mapper in my test. That's not working for some reason. This is the simple test class I've written just to check whether instantiating works or not:

```
@SpringBootTest
public class UtilityTest {

    @Autowired
    private ReviewMapper reviewMapper;

    @Test
    public void test() {
        assertTrue(reviewMapper != null);
    }

}
```

Even before running the test, IDE says "Could not autowire. No beans of 'ReviewMapper' type found.". What can be the problem?

Also, this is my pom.xml file if it can be the case:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.powderize</groupId>
    <artifactId>powderize</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>powderize</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.3.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <org.mapstruct.version>1.2.0.Final</org.mapstruct.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-rest</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- POST INITIALIZR DEPENDENCIES -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <version>1.16.20</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-mail</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.5.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mapstruct</groupId>
            <artifactId>mapstruct</artifactId> <!-- use mapstruct-jdk8 for Java 8 or higher -->
            <version>${org.mapstruct.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- tests -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.5.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source> <!-- or higher, depending on your project -->
                    <target>1.8</target> <!-- or higher, depending on your project -->
                    <annotationProcessorPaths>
                        <path>
                            <groupId>org.mapstruct</groupId>
                            <artifactId>mapstruct-processor</artifactId>
                            <version>${org.mapstruct.version}</version>
                        </path>
                    </annotationProcessorPaths>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>


</project>
```

Comment: Shouldn't be mapstruct-jdk8 instead of mapstruct in your pom.xml?

Comment: it still doesn't work

Comment: Which IDE are you talking about?

Comment: IntelliJ IDEA. I've also installed the Mapstruct plugin

Comment: Which version of IntelliJ? Make sure that you have the latest version they had some bugs which they've fixed lately

Comment: I had version 2017, but just now I've updated it to 2018.3. Still not working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've finally found a solution. I'm not sure about this, but it looks like Mapstruct is somehow connected to Lombok(?) - I'm guessing it because there have been some conflicts between them - adding the plugin also caused the compiler to fail on Lombok's getters. Also, the GitHub link below connects Lombok and Mapstruct, not sure if it's just a coincidence.

Instead of adding plugin like the documentation suggests, I've removed it and created two dependencies instead. Although it's described in the [documentation](http://mapstruct.org/documentation/ide-support/#maven-integration-1), the solution with true, like suggested there, didn't work for me either. I've found a solution on [GitHub](https://github.com/mapstruct/mapstruct-examples/blob/master/mapstruct-lombok/pom.xml).

So, instead of the pom.xml presented in the question, my full pom.xml now looks this way:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.powderize</groupId>
    <artifactId>powderize</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>powderize</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.3.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <org.mapstruct.version>1.2.0.Final</org.mapstruct.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-rest</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- POST INITIALIZR DEPENDENCIES -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <version>1.16.20</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-mail</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.5.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mapstruct</groupId>
            <artifactId>mapstruct-jdk8</artifactId>
            <version>${org.mapstruct.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mapstruct</groupId>
            <artifactId>mapstruct-processor</artifactId>
            <version>${org.mapstruct.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- tests -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Also, working solution confirmed in the test class, both tests passed:

```
@SpringBootTest
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
public class UtilityTests {

    @Autowired
    private ReviewMapper reviewMapper;

    @Test
    public void reviewMapperIsNotNull(){
        assertThat(reviewMapper, notNullValue());
    }

    @Test
    public void testMapper(){
        RideReviewDTO reviewDTO = new RideReviewDTO();
        reviewDTO.setDescription("Test RideReviewDTO description");
        reviewDTO.setUserRating(5.0F);
        RideReview rideReview = reviewMapper.toEntity(reviewDTO);
        assertThat(rideReview.getUserRating(), equalTo(5.0F));
    }

}
```